# Program developed by .net 4.0 sometimes cannot start after reboot

Tags: c#, windows, .net-4.0

I have a program developed by C# and build by .net 4.0.
This program is a windows client which would read the barcode from a barcode reader (via com port) then send the barcode to back-end server via WCF.
The customer have a script in the client OS which would reboot the OS and automatically start up my program every day. The OS is Windows XP Embedded.

Now the problem is, sometimes when the system reboot, my program cannot be started and an error message box will popup to ask whether send this error report to Microsoft.
The most strange thing is, if my colleague copy the program folder and paste as "Copy of ...." in the same folder with the original one the exe under "Copy of ..." one can run without any problem. But the original one still cannot.

What my speculation is maybe the program was writing log and other record files while the system was forced to reboot. And the files get the read/write lock unreleased.

I have uploaded the error screen shots to flickr. Please click here [link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/78738028@N07/) to visit.

Comment: Permission issue after reboot?

Comment: It sounds like maybe there is a pipe clash in the WCF? Did you check the task manager to verify that the process is not started in some state? The Copy Of will probably run as a different name and might work because of that. That is my best guess without seeing code

Comment: Hi Eric J.
We have checked and I think is not the permission problem. Because most of the time it runs OK. And have checked the folder access right, the log in account has full access right.

Comment: Hi Justin Pihony, thanks very much for your advise. But the Copy Of runs as same name

Comment: I have uploaded the error screen shots to flickr. Please click here [link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/78738028@N07/) to visit.Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the actual exception is, we can only guess.

*You will need to catch the exception that is being thrown in your application.*

The best practice is to encapsulate your code in try/catch clauses.

If you are still getting application crashes, then you can attach an event handler to  [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx), or [Application.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.unhandledexception%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and log the exception(s) being received.

Make sure to output the entire exception stack trace, so you can see where it's being thrown from.

Once you've got the exception, if you can't figure out the cause, then ask another question here with that specific detail. eg: "I'm getting an FooException being thrown when I call Bar() after start-up on Windows XP Embedded"

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes after a reboot, some device drivers, or some hardware, will NOT reset itself.   The machine has to be power cycled (turned off and back on) or a command needs to be discovered that will force the device driver and/or hardware to reset.

Comment: But if it is due to the device driver problem, we cannot explain why the Copy Of one can run without problem...

Comment: I'm not an expert but the Device Driver architecture has evolved significantly over the years.  If a new program is invoked, you may get another instance of the device driver (it may have been written to allow multiple program access).  The original instance may be "tied" to the the original program...I'm really guessing here!  However, I have worked on a projects where the hardware and device drivers were wack.  It wasn't fun.

Comment: Thanks Steve Wellens. Thanks very much for this information I will  check this :)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to image IMG_1348 you posted, the error is thrown in your form constructor.

Seems like either code you added or InitializeComponent code is throwing.

Since you are using XPe, you have some options to debug this issue:

1. Add message box statements around the various constructors to show initialization progress. Guard before and after.

   public Form1()
   {
     MessageBox.Show("Before InitializeComponent");
     InitializeComponent();
     MessageBox.Show("After InitializeComponent");

   //MessageBox.Show("Before Other");
     //Other Initialization Code
     //MessageBox.Show("After Other");
   }
2. Attempt to use the remote debugger. I am not sure if this works on XPe, but if it does, and since your code is throwing in the constructor, you need to add code to wait until the debugger is connected.

   public Form1()
   {
     while (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached){ System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0); }
     InitializeComponent();
     //Other Initialization Code
   }